# Is Eclipse not accepting Enter/Return as a null character now?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have made the following simple program that changes normal quotes to TEX quotes

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class TexQuotes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        
        String lines;
        boolean first = true;
        while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
            for (char c: lines.toCharArray())
                if (c == '"') {
                    pw.print(first ? "``" : "''");
                    first = !first;
                }
                else pw.print(c);
            
            pw.println();
        }
        
        br.close();
        pw.flush();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when trying to input something in the Eclipse console and pressing enter, nothing is output back. The code worked fine on an old version of Eclipse, but is Eclipse now not accepting the Enter as a null indicator?

Note: Also, sometimes when pressing Ctrl+Z I get an output, but most often it too does not work. Any other Ctrl + key combination does not work.

Edit: For example, when I enter the following statement as input:

```
"So there are seven now", said John, "and we need to figure out which one."
```

I expect the output:

```
``So there are seven now'', said John, ``and we need to figure out which one.''
```

The problem is that I never exit out of the while loop and so the output is never flushed, because the while loop accepts input until a null character is input. The problem is of course, I don't know how a null character is input in Eclipse.

Comment: Enter is not a "null indicator", it is a line separator. A String with length = 0 is not equal to null, and never has been.

Comment: For reading standard input, it is preferable to use class [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) which has been part of the JDK since Java 5. Also, you don't need to wrap `System.out` in a `PrintWriter` in order to write to standard output.

Comment: @Taschi Yes I already know this, but Eclipse way of entering null was to just press enter after an empty string, at least that's what I remember.

Comment: I am 99.9% sure you remember wrongly. By pressing enter after an empty string, you submit an empty string.

Comment: @Abra I agree Scanner is a easier and preferable, but I used a BufferedReader because input can get too large and Scanner is a bit slower. Also, what should I use instead of System.out - as there is no constructor of PrintWriter that accepts no arguments?

Comment: Static member `out` of class `System` is an instance of class `PrintStream`, Just use the methods of class `PrintStream` to write to standard output. Class `PrintStream` also has a `print()` method that takes a single parameter of type `char`.

Comment: @Abra OK, but shouldn't `PrintStream` be used in situations like dealing with files or sending something over the network, both in the form of bytes, while `PrintWriter` is usually used when dealing with plain text? And you also have to specify the output through the constructor argument, too, right?

Comment: readine returns null if and only if the end of the data stream is reached.  'Enter' is not an indication of end of data stream.  I can't tell you what is an indication in Eclipse since I don't use it.  On a Linux terminal ctrl/d is the indicator; on a Windows console window, ctrl/z followed by Enter.

Comment: @user13784117 I understand, but I have already tried ctrl+z and ctr+z followed by enter, which, strangely, sometimes works and most other times doesn't! That's what gets me confused.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question and post a sample input line that the user should enter when running your code and what you expect to see displayed on the computer screen for that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TexQuotes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
        while (stdin.hasNextLine()) {
            line = stdin.nextLine();
            boolean start = true;
            while (line.indexOf('"') >= 0) {
                if (start) {
                    line = line.replaceFirst("\"", "``");
                    start = false;
                }
                else {
                    line = line.replaceFirst("\"", "''");
                    start = true;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println("    ***  TexQuotes.main() completed  ***");
    }
}
```

You terminate the `while` loop by entering *end of file*, i.e. Ctrl+Z on Windows, by itself.
Until you enter *end of file*, you enter a line of text and then press ENTER key.
After pressing ENTER key, all double quote characters in the entered text are replaced alternately by your *tex* quotes.

### EDIT

Using `BufferedReader` and `PrintWriter`...

```java
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);
try {
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        boolean start = true;
        while (line.indexOf('"') >= 0) {
            if (start) {
                line = line.replaceFirst("\"", "``");
                start = false;
            }
            else {
                line = line.replaceFirst("\"", "''");
                start = true;
            }
        }
        pw.println(line);
        pw.flush();
        line = br.readLine();
    }
}
catch (IOException xIo) {
    xIo.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Yes this is done using `Scanner` and `System.out.println()`, but what about if I want to achieve the same thing using `BufferedReader` and `PrintWriter`?